# Нужно, чтобы считывалась информация с Entry в txt файл

Tags: python, tkinter

```
a = open("sort.txt", "w+")

def give():
        v=Entry19.get()
give()
a.write('v')
a.close()
btn = Button(root, text="Записать в\nфайл entry", font='TimesNewRoman 10', height = 2, width = 15, bg="white",
             command=give)
btn.grid(row=22, column=9, sticky=W)
    

root.mainloop()
```

Entry19 это переменная entry, соотвествующая 1row и 2column (Длина 1)
в тексте он выводит букву v, а мне надо данные из ячейки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Напишите пожалуйста, на примере моего кода

Comment: Уже оформил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все что не в функциях и выше вызова `root.mainloop()` выполняется сразу при запуске программы, вам же надо чтобы открытие файла, запись в него, закрытие файла выполнялось только после нажатия на кнопку, поэтому все это нужно перенести в саму функцию обработчик нажатия на кнопку. Через `write` нужно писать не символ `'v'`, а значение переменной `v`. Вызывать функцию `give` вручную тоже не нужно - она вызовется "сама" при нажатии на кнопку, т.к. вы указали ее как обработчик нажатия.

```
def give():
    a = open("sort.txt", "w+")
    v=Entry19.get()
    a.write(v)
    a.close()

btn = Button(root, text="Записать в\nфайл entry", font='TimesNewRoman 10', height = 2, width = 15, bg="white",
             command=give)
```